# Compute $\mathbb{E}[W(t)\int_0^t W(s)ds]$

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

$W(t)$ is Brownian a motion. I proved the title using Itô lemma for the product of two Itô processes.

Let $Y(t) = \int_0^t W(s)ds$

$W(t)Y(t) = \int_0^t W(s)dY(s) + \int_0^t Y(s) dW(s) + \int_0^t dW(t)dY(t)   = \int_0^t W^2(s)ds + \int_0^t Y(s) dW(s) + 0$

Since the second term is a martingale, taking expectation on both side I obtain :

$\mathbb{E}[W(t)\int_0^t W(s)ds] = \mathbb{E}[\int_0^t W^2(s)ds] = \int_0^t\mathbb{E}[W^2(s)]ds = \frac{t^2}{2}$

Is everything ok in my algebra ? Do you see a less brutal way to compute $\mathbb{E}[W(t)\int_0^t W(s)ds]$ ?

Comment: Direct way: $$E\left(W(t)\int_0^tW(s)ds\right)=\int_0^tE(W(t)W(s))ds=\int_0^tsds=\frac{t^2}2$$